# Cloning an Object in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to clone a DTO. I have taken a DTO Object as shown:

```
public class Employee implements Cloneable 
{

    String name;
    String dept;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

}
```

But this line is giving me Error :

```
public class Test 
{

        public static void main(String args[]) {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setDept("10");
        emp1.setName("Kiran");
        Employee emp2 = (Employee) emp1.clone(); // This Line is giving error .


    }
}
```

My query is that clone method is from `Object`, so why can't we use it directly like we do the `toString Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, never mind. You need to override the clone method in your class since its protected in java.lang.Object. Don't forget to remove the CloneNotSupportedException in the method signature, so that you don't have to handle it everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 8):

You have to override Object.clone(), which is protected. See the
[java.lang.Cloneable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and [Object.clone()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) documentation.

More complete example here: [How to implement Cloneable interface](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-implement-cloneable-interface.html).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately [cloning in Java is broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html). If you have an option, either try to define your own clone interface, one which *actually* has a `clone` method or use copy constructors to create copies of object.