# How to copy a (JavaBean) object's state into another, existing object?

Tags: java, object, copy, clone, javabeans

Image you have a class that looks as follows:

```
class Foo
{
   public String x;
   public int y;
   public long l;
}
```

then somewhere we have:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
foo1.x = "a";
foo1.y = 3;
foo1.l = 2L;
```

and then somewhere else we have another Foo object whose fields have not been initialized.

```
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
//foo2 = foo1;
```

Given that assigning a reference to the object represented by the variable foo1 to the variable foo2 is not what I want to do here, since I want to preserve the reference to the object represented by foo2, what's the simplest way to copy the state of foo1 to foo2?

In other words, how do I do this automatically?

```
foo2.x = foo1.x;
foo2.y = foo1.y;
foo2.l = foo1.l;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloning an Object in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635175/cloning-an-object-in-java)

Comment: you are not losing the reference to foo2, u are just setting properties

Comment: This is almost the opposite of "cloning" an object. The idea is not to end up with a brand new object that mirrors the state of another object. The idea is to reinitialize an existing object with the state of another object.

Comment: Not many people seem to be reading the word "existing" in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Foo was a JavaBean that is if it had proper setters / getters instead of public fields you could use Apache Commons `Beanutils.copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)`

Comment: that might be what I'm looking for. I'll check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no `MOVE CORRESPONDING` in Java. You will need to write it out in full (or "some other hack").

The code is not idiomatic for Java. There's public fields there. Probably a better way of handling the situation, which isn't described, would be to have an immutable `Foo`. You may then have an object with a reference to `Foo` that is mutable.

Answer (score 1):

create a copy constructor

```
class Foo
{
   public String x;
   public int y;
   public long l;

   public Foo(Foo foo){
       this.x = foo.x;
       this.y = foo.y;
       this.l = foo.l;
   }
}
```

Now you can use this like

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
foo1.x = "a";
foo1.y = 3;
foo1.l = 2L;

Foo foo2 = new Foo(foo1);
```

You can also do this by implemening clone method. But I think the creating the copy constructor is better and easier way. check this link of [effective java](http://books.google.com.bd/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=effective%2bjava%2bclone&source=bl&ots=yXGhLnv4O4&sig=zvEip5tp5KGgwqO1sCWgtGyJ1Ns&hl=en&ei=CYANSqygK8jktgfM-JGcCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=effective%2bjava%2bclone&f=false)

Comment: haha.. our answers looks like they are created using a copy consturctor :P

Answer (score 0):

You could either implement a ***copy constructor*** like

```
public Foo (Foo foo) {
   this.x = foo.getX();
   this.y = foo.getY();
   this.z = foo.getZ();
}
```

and then create a new copy of `Foo` as

```
Foo foo2 = new Foo(foo1);
```

Or, you could have your ***Foo implements Cloneable*** and define `clone()` as

```
public Foo clone() {
    return new Foo(this.x, this.y, this.z);
}
```

and then create a copy using `clone()` as

```
Foo foo2 = foo1.clone();
```

Please, **note** that *you may skip defining `clone()` (here) because by **default** the `Object.clone()` implementation does a shallow copy and it would work with the simple fields you have here.*

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `Cloneable` interface and copy constructors, there is another solution: the [freeze/thaw pattern](https://github.com/fge/btf/wiki/The-freeze-thaw-pattern).

This is a pattern which allows you to obtain a builder from an object, *with all the state of that object prefilled*, modify it if needed, and freeze it again. If you implement it, you can do:

```
final Foo foo2 = foo.thaw().freeze();
```

**The bonus point is that all instances of `Foo` are immutable: no setters anymore!** To modify:

```
final Foo foo2 = foo.thaw().setY(something).freeze();
```

This is JavaBeans with none of the drawbacks and the power of the builder pattern to boot.

Answer (score 0):

You could have Foo implement the `Cloneable` interface and override the method `clone`. 
In the method's body, you initialize a new Foo and assign this Foo's field's values to the new Foo.